# Rails join table not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join

Hi I am playing around in rails and have built a little listing application.

My application has a listing model that has many tags through a has and belongs to many join table.

the join table is called listings_tags

The problem I have is that I cannot save the listing_tag association during create or update.

I can see in console

```
Started PATCH "/listings/92" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-08-15 12:45:58 +1000
Processing by ListingsController#update as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"5isdLs2FiToZxtm1ZVPP0y0lKtnfyoLA8Njv4GBwWVH1M3TIm2IUW9ts5RR06OpQz8tgSBitZ7Rm69uVIifevQ==", "listing"=>{"name"=>"Canteen Coffee", "streetAddres"=>"19 Park Avenue", "suburb_id"=>"31", "post_code_id"=>"2", "region_id"=>"1", "country_id"=>"2", "telephone"=>"+61416650204", "url"=>"http://canteencoffee.com.au/canteen-kitchen/", "tag_ids"=>["", "1"]}, "commit"=>"Update Listing", "id"=>"92"}
  Listing Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE "listings"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 92], ["LIMIT", 1]]
Unpermitted parameter: :tag_ids
   (1.8ms)  BEGIN
  Suburb Load (5.4ms)  SELECT  "suburbs".* FROM "suburbs" WHERE "suburbs"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 31], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (1.7ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/listings/92
Completed 302 Found in 21ms (ActiveRecord: 9.0ms)
```

Obviously my issue is the :tag_ids

so I tried changing my listing params.require(:listing).permit() to include listing_attributes: [:id], tags: [:id] and :tag_ids

its killing me :) please help

Listing Model

```
class Listing < ApplicationRecord

  has_and_belongs_to_many :tags
  belongs_to :suburb
  has_one :post_code, through: :suburb
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags

  def self.search(term)
    if term
      where('name LIKE ?', "%#{term}%")
    else
      order('id DESC')
    end
  end


end
```

Tag Model

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :listings
end
```

Listings Tags Schema

```
create_table "listings_tags", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "listing_id", null: false
    t.bigint "tag_id", null: false
    t.index ["listing_id", "tag_id"], name: "index_listings_tags_on_listing_id_and_tag_id"
  end
```

Listings Controller

```
class ListingsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_listing, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /listings
  # GET /listings.json
  def index
    @listings = Listing.search(params[:term])
  end

  # GET /listings/1
  # GET /listings/1.json
  def show
    @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
    @tags = @listing.tags
    @suburb = @listing.suburb
    @postcode = @suburb.post_code
  end

  # GET /listings/new
  def new
    @listing = Listing.new
  end

  # GET /listings/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /listings
  # POST /listings.json
  def create
    @listing = Listing.new(listing_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.save
        format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @listing }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /listings/1
  # PATCH/PUT /listings/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @listing.update(listing_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @listing, notice: 'Listing was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @listing }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /listings/1
  # DELETE /listings/1.json
  def destroy
    @listing.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to listings_url, notice: 'Listing was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_listing
      @listing = Listing.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def listing_params
      params.require(:listing).permit(:name, :streetAddress, :telephone, :url, :term, :suburb_id, :post_code_id, :region_id, :country_id, :tag_ids)
    end
end
```

Tags Controller

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_tag, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /tags
  # GET /tags.json
  def index
    @tags = Tag.all
  end

  # GET /tags/1
  # GET /tags/1.json
  def show
    @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
    @listings = @tag.listings
  end

  # GET /tags/new
  def new
    @tag = Tag.new
  end

  # GET /tags/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /tags
  # POST /tags.json
  def create
    @tag = Tag.new(tag_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @tag.save
        format.html { redirect_to @tag, notice: 'Tag was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @tag }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @tag.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /tags/1
  # PATCH/PUT /tags/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @tag.update(tag_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @tag, notice: 'Tag was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @tag }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @tag.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /tags/1
  # DELETE /tags/1.json
  def destroy
    @tag.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tags_url, notice: 'Tag was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_tag
      @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def tag_params
      params.require(:tag).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

Form

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(@listing, local: true) do |form| %>
  <%= form.text_field :name, id: :listing_name %>
  <%= form.text_field :streetAddress, id: :listing_streetAddress %>
  <%= form.collection_select(:suburb_id, Suburb.all, :id, :name) %>
  <%= form.collection_select(:post_code_id, PostCode.all, :id, :number) %>
  <%= form.collection_select(:region_id, Region.all, :id, :name) %>
  <%= form.collection_select(:country_id, Country.all, :id, :name) %>
  <%= form.text_field :telephone, id: :listing_telephone %>
  <%= form.text_field :url, id: :listing_url %>
  <%= form.select :tag_ids, Tag.all.pluck(:name, :id), {}, { multiple: true, class: "selectize" } %>
  <%= form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

I really appreciate your help. I am sure it is probably something simple that I am doing wrong.

Comment: The log from your console shows `"tag_ids"=>["", "1"]`. Shouldn't it just take one value (an ID) that's not an array?

Comment: has_and_belongs_to_many hence the array... a listing has multiple tags.... am I doing it the wrong way?

Comment: Oops sorry, misread! That should be fine

Comment: @bwalshy i appreciate your input

Comment: I find it weird that you're getting an `Unpermitted parameter` error and not a `ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'tag_ids' for Listing)` error

Comment: I'm not sure how much this will do, but instead of `:tag_ids` as the attribute name in #listing_params, try replacing that with `tags_attributes: [:id, :name]`. (Note that I specified "tags" to be plural. That tells rails that more than one child model's attributes could be given)

Comment: Then try in your rails console: `Listing.find(92).update_attributes(tags_attributes: [{id: 1, 'Existing Tag'}, {name: 'New Tag Name'}])` and see if that works. If it does then that's good and your only issue then is to update the markup for that select in your form

Comment: 2.4.2 :005 > Listing.find(92).update_attributes(tags_attributes: {id: 1, 'Existing Tag'}, {name: 'Full Food Menu'})
SyntaxError: (irb):5: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting =>
butes: {id: 1, 'Existing Tag'}, {name: 'Full Food Menu'})
                              ^
(irb):5: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting end-of-input
g'}, {name: 'Full Food Menu'})

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178052/discussion-between-bwalshy-and-joe-bloggs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
params.require(:listing).permit(:name, :streetAddress, :telephone, :url, :term, :suburb_id, :post_code_id, :region_id, :country_id, :tag_ids => [])
```

source : https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters

Comment: 2.4.2 :012 > Listing.find(92).update_attributes(tags_attributes: [{id: 1, name: 'Full Food Menu'}])
  Listing Load (2.6ms)  SELECT  "listings".* FROM "listings" WHERE "listings"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", 92], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
  Tag Load (1.4ms)  SELECT "tags".* FROM "tags" INNER JOIN "listings_tags" ON "tags"."id" = "listings_tags"."tag_id" WHERE "listings_tags"."listing_id" = $1 AND "tags"."id" = 1  [["listing_id", 92]]
   (0.6ms)  ROLLBACK
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find Tag with ID=1 for Listing with ID=92
        from (irb):12